# Exception of a method not handled and code compiles successfully

Tags: java, exception

```
public class ExceptionDemo {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        try {
            bar();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        foo();
    }

    public static void bar() {

    }

    public static void foo() throws NullPointerException {

    }
}
```

Please explain me why this code compiles successfully even though we didn't handle `foo()` method exception.

Comment: Because `throws NullPointerException` is useless. *Everything* throws a NPE. Furthermore, it is a `RuntimeException` and does not need handling.

Answer (score 2):

In java we have two exception,

```
1) Checked Exception (Compile Time Exception)
2) Unchecked Exception (Runtime Exception)
```

**NullPointerException is a Runtime Exception**, means it will get checked at Runtime.

Here in your example **Foo()** method propagating **NullPointeException** by throws keyword to the calling method so at the time of compilation it is okay but if somehow NullPointerException will be thrown at runtime your code will break.

**Recommendation:** You should handle it by checking **null** rather than propagating it by **throws**.

for more details you can check http://technostepup.com/CoreJava/ExceptionHandling/exception-types.php

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException in Java is a RuntimeException and so the compiler does not force you to use a try-catch block to handle it appropriately. We need not handle Runtime Exceptions using try catch block, but if it is a Compile Time Exception like FileNotFoundException then you need to add the try catch Block.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Exception and Error classes are inherited from Throwable class. Exception and Error classes has subclasses.

If your code throw an Exception (except RunTimeException) you must catch this exception. But If your code throw a RunTimeException or Error you doesn't have to catch RunTimeException or Error but you can.

Throwable, Exception and Exception subclasses (except RunTimeException) are checked Exception, so you have to catch this exceptions.

But RunTimeException and Error classes are unchecked Exceptions, so you doesn't have to catch. You should try that your code doesn't throw unchecked Exceptions in runtime.

Comment: You don't *have to* rewrite the program. You can catch the runtime exceptions if you wish, but it is probably a bad idea.